# Primefaces PostConstruct and SessionHolder

Tags: jsf-2, spring-security

I have a problem in integrating Spring Security with JSF
I'm trying to access to the `Authentication` Object in a @PostConstruct method and retrieve the user login
and after I want to retrieve the user's object from database the problem is that I can't get the `Authentication` object because it's not constructed before login

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    //here I have the exception because auth is null 
    String name = auth.getName(); 
    lecteur =(Lecteur)userService.getUserByLogin(name);     
}
```

How to solve this problem ?